# How to replace and edit content of file?

Tags: bash, scripts, perl, regex

I have a file which contains the following content:

```
set0027:
set0027_100-250
set0027_1-150
set0027_50-200

set0038:
set0038_100-250
set0038_1-150
set0038_50-200
```

I want to modify it in the following way:

```
cd set0027
clustalw INFILE=set0027_100-250 OUTFILE=set0027_100-250.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0027_1-150 OUTFILE=set0027_1-150.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0027_50-200 OUTFILE=set0027_50-200.aln
cd ..
cd set0038
clustalw INFILE=set0038_100-250 OUTFILE=set0038_100-250.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0038_1-150 OUTFILE=set0038_1-150.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0038_50-200 OUTFILE=set0038_50-200.aln
cd ..
```

How can I do this using bash script?

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result ? Are there any errors ? We don't do programming or homework for you, but will try to find the problems if you share what you have tried and where/how it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$ perl -npe 's/(.*):/cd \1/; s/^(set.*)/clustalw INFILE=\1 OUTFILE=\1.aln/; s/^\s+/cd ..\n/;' file
cd set0027
clustalw INFILE=set0027_100-250 OUTFILE=set0027_100-250.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0027_1-150 OUTFILE=set0027_1-150.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0027_50-200 OUTFILE=set0027_50-200.aln
cd ..
cd set0038
clustalw INFILE=set0038_100-250 OUTFILE=set0038_100-250.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0038_1-150 OUTFILE=set0038_1-150.aln
clustalw INFILE=set0038_50-200 OUTFILE=set0038_50-200.aln
```

uses command line options

```
-n implicit loop
-e execute perl inline
-p print line
```